# How do you activate the Shockwave 1st/2nd Strike's effect?

Tags: fate-extra

In the Shockwave 1st Strike armor, it says that it gives me a power to stun enemies:

> release_mgi(c);   : Field attack: Stuns nearby foe.

How do you activate this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From This GameFAQs post [How does Shockwave - 1st Strike work?](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/975333-fate-extra/61332228)

> Press X on the field. Your Servant will attack, and launch a shockwave forward. If it hits an enemy, they'll be stunned. If you start a battle while they're stunned, they will remain stunned for the first action of combat.
>
> Shockwave - Second Strike raises that to the first two actions. Oddly enough, Shockwave - Third Strike does NOT make it into three actions; in fact it takes it back down to one action. So Second Strike is the best of the three.